# Corda Node Database Unknown property 'schema'

Tags: java, postgresql, corda

I get the following error when trying to perform ./build/nodes/runnodes for my cordapp. The party (Mint) which I want to connect to a standalone Postgresql database is giving this error:

```
[ERROR] 01:07:58-0400 [main] subcommands.ValidateConfigurationCli. - Error(s) while parsing node configuration:
    - for path: "database.schema": Unknown property 'schema'.
```

In my node.conf file for a party (Mint) is

```
dataSourceProperties = {
    dataSourceClassName = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
    dataSource.url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sample_db"
    dataSource.user = mint
    dataSource.password = my_password
}
database = {
    transactionIsolationLevel = READ_COMMITTED
    schema = mint
}

# When JDBC driver is not placed into node's 'drivers' directory then add absolute path:
jarDirs = ['/Users/sayefiqbal/Documents/Corda/Metals-cordapp/build/nodes/Mint/drivers/postgresql-42.2.12.jar']
```

Note sure what is the issue. Followed documentation from Corda but no resolution so far.

Comment: are you using open source or enterprise?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using the Community edition of Corda, It doesn't have the `schema` property available. However, you could specify the schema in the JDBC URL as below:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sample_db?currentSchema=mint
```

Refer documentation for details: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/node-database.html#postgresql.

Comment: I specified the url as described above, but getting a different error now.

Comment: [ERROR] 13:13:06-0400 [main] pool.HikariPool. - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization. [errorCode=cmpazk, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.4/cmpazk]
[ERROR] 13:13:06-0400 [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging. - Could not connect to the database. Please check your JDBC connection URL, or the connectivity to the database.: Could not connect to the database. Please check your JDBC connection URL, or the connectivity to the database. [errorCode=ltejww, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.4/ltejww]

Comment: It seems there is something wrong with your JDBC URL or database connectivity as the error mentions. Please validate if everything is correct.

Comment: The issue was with he user/group. Had to use default user postgres in order to access the schema. It works now. However, does the database store information about the contents of the transaction, e.g. values of the states. I don't see any such table created by corda.